# Calling java command line applications

Tags: java, shell, powershell, command-line, powershell-4.0

So I have the following command that runs java application from the command line and produces a bunch of output.

```
java -jar client.jar --server test7.contoso.com --alternativeemailaddress fred1@contoso.com --organisation contoso --emailaddress fred@contoso.com --data1 1234 --Password1 123456 --data2 1234 --Password2 1234
```

I'm trying to run this from within PowerShell and capture the output to a variable for further processing.

So far I've found 100's of different ways to do this, but none have really worked particularly well.

Is there any best practice/convention as to how to get this done?

Comment: Is there anything Java-y to this? Seems like the question is really, "how do I capture output from a program in PowerShell," is that right? Regardless, rather than saying that you've found 100s of ways that don't work for you, you should describe what _specifically_ isn't working in one of those ways. Otherwise, the best we can give you is a high-level description of what to do, which will probably be one of the 100s of ways you've tried.

Comment: 100 different ways..... Care to show _one_ that didn't and any errors you got so we can help explain what went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2012/03/03/using-windows-powershell-to-run-old-command-line-tools-and-their-weirdest-parameters/
For many ways to execute "legacy" commands with PowerShell

You need to include the .exe for one.
The new V3+ recommended way is to use --% to tell PowerShell to not parse the remaining arguments

```
PS> java.exe --% -jar client.jar --server test7.contoso.com --alternativeemailaddress fred1@contoso.com --organisation contoso --emailaddress fred@contoso.com --data1 1234 --Password1 123456 --data2 1234 --Password2 1234
```

Comment: Yes nothing seems to make much sense. This looks promising and I will read the article and try you example. Many thanks

Comment: Keep in mind that PowerShell is an object based system and all legacy or cross platform command line tools are text based, so serialization applies just as it would in C# or Java @user1513388

Answer (score 0):

OK so I worked it out. This is what I went with.

```
$params = @{ 'jar'='C:\client\client.jar';
             'param1'='data1'
             'param2'='data2'
             'param3'='data3'
             'param4'='data4'
             'param5'='data5'
             'param6'='data6'
             'param7'='data7'
             'param8'='data8'
             'param9'='data9'
             'param10'='data10'
             'error_log'='C:\tmp\error_log.txt' 
             }

$data = & 'C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe' -jar $params.'jar' `
           --param1 $params.param1 `
           --param2 $params.param2 `
           --param3 $params.param3 `
           --param4 $params.param4 `
           --param5 $params.param5 `
           --param6 $params.param6 `
           --param7 $params.param7 `
           --param8 $params.param8 `
           --param9 $params.param9 `
           --param10 $params.param10 `
            2>$params.error_log
```